# Как можно изменить инверсию драйвера l298n для запитки rgb ленты

Tags: c++, arduino

Тут такое дело подключаю rgb ленту к ардуино через l298n драйвер, и когда прописываю analogWrite(LED_R,255); то он гаснет, а по умолчанию горит.
Вкратце 255 это 0, а 0 это 255 как можно исправить

[image: Вот схема]

Answer (score 0):

Программирование на С++ для микроконтроллером имеет свои плюсы, например, можно производить на свет грязные хаки и делать вид, что так и надо:

```
namespace myHacks {
  inline void analogWrite(int pin, int val) {
    if(pin==LED_R) {
      ::analogWrite(pin, 255-val)
    } else {
      ::analogWrite(pin, val)
    }
  }
}

using namespace myHacks;
```